# How to get inner content of Content editor web part Programatically using Client side Object model

Tags: visual-studio, csom

I am unable to get Inner content(rich text value) of Content Editor web part, Please Provide some code sample on how to do this

Comment: What have you tried so far yourself? The better you specify your question, the easier and more likely you'll get the answer you need.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code example:

```
$("textarea[Title='System Description']").closest("span").find("iframe[Title='Rich Text Editor']").blur(function(){
  alert($(this).contents().find("body").html());
});
```

In which the System Description is the rich text editor.

For more details here is the great sample explained by Marc: [Finding the Contents of a SharePoint Rich Text Column with jQuery](http://sympmarc.com/2011/02/10/finding-the-contents-of-a-sharepoint-rich-text-column-with-jquery/)

Also one thread was answered on Stackoverflow here: [Retrieving rich text box sharepoint in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874536/retrieving-rich-text-box-sharepoint-in-javascript)